# iOS Enterprise Distribution app QR code Download Issue

Tags: ios, ota, enterprise-distribution, ios-enterprise

We are trying to create a QR code of this URL:

`itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://url/app.plist`

So that if user scans the QR code, they should get a popup for installation of the app.

We created the QR code, so when we scan it takes you to Safari but the installation doesn't work.

Also, when I hit this URL from app programmatically, it works.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://url/app.plist"]]
```

but when I manually add it in browser then it doesn't work.

Can someone guide me? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work when you enter it in Safari because Safari itself does not support that URL scheme? (`itms-services://`). `+[UIApplication openURL:]` should employ whatever apps/means available to open a given URL, but that's not necessarily going to be Safari. However, this still does not explain why the QR code does not work...?

Comment: What QR reader are you using, and what version of iOS?

Comment: AT&T QR code scanner ,in iOS 8 and iOS 9

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided lacks a colon after the URL scheme. This:

```
itms-services//?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://url/app.plist
```

should look like this instead:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://url/app.plist
```

If your URL is actually correct, then you should check your manifest file to make sure that you have all the required elements.

Comment: sorry tats my misprint,it not an issue of colon

Comment: Right -- sorry for the confusion.

Comment: plist is fine .Its working .what changes sud i have to make